# I want permanent change in html with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing problem with js. I have a like button, I want when people click on my like button it will add 1 in count. and also when I click on my 2-6 button they add 1 in my very first button. Is there any solution ? check out this website for better understand www.webcrews.net

I want this change will be permanent even after refresh.

```js
var clicks = 0;

function onClick(){
 clicks += 1;
 document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 return false;
};
```

```css
.like_btn{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:5%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    left: 5%;
 
}

.fa-thumbs-o-up{
 float:left;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.count{
margin-left:15px;
font-family:"Lato" , sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single_portfolio">
                            <div class="portfolio_overlay">
                                <div class="portfolio_hover top-1_hover">
                                    <a href="">VIEW</a>
                                    <h6>Agrodristi</h6>
                                    <p>Web Development</p>
                                    <div class="like_btn"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" onClick="onClick()"></i><span class="count" id="clicks">0</span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <img src="img/top-1.jpg" alt="portfolio" />
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="single_portfolio">
                            <div class="portfolio_overlay">
                                <div class="portfolio_hover top-2_hover">
                                    <a href="">VIEW</a>
                                    <h6>Telemax</h6>
                                    <p>Web Development</p>
                                    <div class="like_btn"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" onClick="onClick()"></i><span class="count" id="clicks">0</span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <img src="img/top-2.jpg" alt="portfolio" />
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="single_portfolio">
                            <div class="portfolio_overlay">
                                <div class="portfolio_hover top-3_hover">
                                    <a href="">VIEW</a>
                                    <h6>FZ Pizza</h6>
                                    <p>Web Design & Development</p>
                                   <div class="like_btn"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" onClick="onClick()"></i><span class="count" id="clicks">0</span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                               <img src="img/top-3.jpg" alt="portfolio" />
                            
                        </div>
```

Comment: you want to hold the value of click ?

Comment: You need to store that click count somewhere. Use SQL database or similar maybe.

Comment: yes I want to hold the value of clicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to iterate your counter on the server, using a server-side technology like PHP, Node.js, Python, Java or something along those lines. You will create a route that processes the request, increments your counter, then returns a response with some sort of success / failure message. To store your count you can use a DB (like MySQL), a key-value store (like Redis) or just a flat file... depends on how much you want to challenge yourself.

If you're interested in learning how to implement some simple AJAX processing, have a look at this short [AJAX + PHP tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php).

Answer (score 1):

You need a data service to store the change, and in your application you will need to add xhr calls to the service to get the data.

In short, without using a service or using localstorage, you cannot make permanent change after refreshing.